# Move MySQL database to a new server

Tags: mysql

What's the easiest way to move mysql schemas (tables, data, everything) from one server to another?

Is there an easy method move all this from one server running mysql to another also already running mysql?

Comment: are these built in commands? I'm brand new to this.

Comment: If you have any kind of control panel like CPanel, Plesk, etc., on the servers you are using, then chances are that you have access to phpMyAdmin which has export and import features.

Comment: @Kevin Nelson thanks, we only have shell access

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dump the Database either using `mysqldump` or if you are using PHPMyAdmin then Export the structure and data.

For `mysqldump` you will require the console and use the following command:

`mysqldump -u <user> -p -h <host> <dbname> > /path/to/dump.sql`

Then in the other server:

`mysql -u <user> -p <dbname> < /path/to/dump.sql`

Comment: have added the syntax above for you - I shall double check that now

Comment: This website should help you do it step by step :) http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Backing-up-and-restoring-your-MySQL-Database/

Comment: This is only a half answer. Where's the import part?

Comment: I moved database this method and events gone. Leave this note here to help someone before it's too late.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using SSH keys:

```
$ mysqldump --all-databases -u[user] -p[pwd] | ssh [host/IP] mysql -u[user] -p[pwd]
```

If you are NOT using SSH keys:

```
$ mysqldump --all-databases -u[user] -p[pwd] | ssh user@[host/IP] mysql -u[user] -p[pwd]
```

WARNING: You'll want to clear your history after this to avoid anyone finding your passwords.

```
$ history -c
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, copied all databases real quickly to my new system!!

Comment: How is adding "user@" correlated to use of ssh keys? Just curious.

Answer (score 5):

If you're moving from the same architecture to the same architecture (x86->x86, x86_64 -> x86_64), you can just rsync your MySQL datadir from one server to the other.  Obviously, you should not run this while your old MySQL daemon is running.

If your databases are InnoDB-based, then you will want to make sure that your InnoDB log files have been purged and their contents merged to disk before you copy files.  You can do this by setting `innodb_fast_shutdown` to `0` (the default is `1`, which will **not** flush the logs to disk), which will cause the log file to be flushed on the next server shutdown.  You can do this by logging on to MySQL as root, and in the MySQL shell, do:

`SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0`

Or by setting the option in your my.cnf and restarting the server to pull in the change, then shutting down to flush the log.

Do something like:

```
#On old server (notice the ending slash and lack thereof, it's very important)
rsync -vrplogDtH /var/mysql root@other.server:/var/mysql/
#Get your my.cnf
scp /etc/my.cnf root@other.server:/etc/my.cnf
```

After that you might want to run `mysql_upgrade [-p your_root_password]` to make sure the databases are up-to-date.

I will say it's worked for me in the (very recent) past (moving from an old server to a new one, both running FreeBSD 8.x), but YMMV depending on how many versions you were in the past.

Comment: I you do this, there are a lot of different little things that can go wrong, especially if there are InnoDB tables. I'd suggest using [Percona's xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start) for a task like that.

Comment: Sadly the architecture is different, though I'm sure others will appreciate this advice.

Comment: @Wrikken Do you know of any documentation on **what* might go wrong using this method?  I believe you (there are lots of little things that _could_ go wrong), but I was wondering if there was a definitive list on why not to do it like this.

Comment: Sadly I'm not aware of a definitive list, but innodb-logs yet to play out is a biggie for instance, afaik percona's solution is just scripts, so you could delve around to see what kinds of problems they are expecting & preventing.

Comment: @Wrikken If the major concern is InnoDB logs not being played out, then you can have them flushed to disk on shutdown.  I updated the answer to include how you could do that.

Comment: @galador: one of the concerns, not _the major_, but just a bigger one. Then again, 95% of the time this method does work, and if the other server is still available if it doesn't, the OP might just go for it, good chance it will work.