# mysql- move transactional data from one mysql server to another mysql server

Tags: mysql

I took a back up of my production server and created new server few weeks before. I want to move some transactional data from my production to the backup server.what is the best way to do this?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Move everything to a new server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283301/mysql-move-everything-to-a-new-server)

Comment: i don't wan't to move everything i just want to move some transactional data.this contains many tables. using postgres/oracle i was having an option to connect to other db via db link.

Comment: How should your application work if some data is here and some is there? Are you looking for a master/slave setup?

Comment: No. One of client moved to new environment so they are still having some data in my old production environment .

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, it's hard to understand what you want to move and where (you are talking about "old production", "new production", and "backup" servers, I don't understand which is which).

Anyway, there is no db link in MySQL. However you could have a look at the [FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html) which will allow you to connect to a table on old server from the new server. Then run the insert/update/delete queries on the new server to move the data.