# Which MySQL InnoDb files to move when transfering to a new server?

Tags: mysql

I'm moving a 150GB MySQL Server to a brand new machine on the same network, both of them run Windows Server 2012.

The new server runs **MySQL 8.0.15** while the old one runs on **MySQL 5.7.14**

All of my tables are in the '**roat**' folder.

This is my rough plan

1. Shut down both MySQL Servers
2. Start a Filezilla transfer, moving all the MySQL files over
3. Start the new MySQL Server.

Now my question is, which of these files below will I need to transfer to the new server in order for the new server to work and startup?

edit: I am not interested in using mysqldump since it's at least 10x slower with 150GB of data.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move MySQL database to a new server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283301/move-mysql-database-to-a-new-server)

Comment: I am not using 'mysqldump' to transfer the database, since it'd be super slow (up to 20 hours total, while moving the raw 150GB of files over would be max 1 hour)

Comment: @PhillipJ that's an inherent problem of MySQL and dumps. If you have the Enterprise edition, either bought or compiled from source, you can take real backups and restore them on the new server. Check [Moving or Copying InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html) for other options. Copying/moving files *is* possible but requires care - you can't just copy data files while transactions are still active. You'd end up with partial or corrupted data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm okay with an hour or 2 downtime (shutting down the mysql server), would that not be possible?

Comment: One option is to use the [transferable tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html) feature, although that requires that the tables were created with the `innodb_file_per_table` option. In that case you need to flush the tables and copy the files. Another option is described as a ["cold backup"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-backup.html) but in reality it means that you shut down the server and copy the files over

Comment: @PhillipJ the best option would be to use the Enterprise backup. After that, the "cold backup" page explains what you need to move. You should try it first to make sure everything works ate least once though, on a new server

Comment: I don't have MySQL Enterprise and I can't afford it ($5K), if I have 'innodb_file_per_table' enabled, would I be able to just move the 'roat' folder and all the tables would appear on the new server when I start it up?

Comment: Safest is to make a SQL dump and import it instead of file copying.. Then you dont have to deal with possible  binary file changes between major MySQL versions.  File copying between MySQL 5 and MySQL 8 is not adviced to do because it's a major version update. File copying is more safer where the major versions is the same like MySQL version 8.0.11 and version 8.0.13 for example.

Comment: Thanks for that info @RaymondNijland, I've downgraded the other server to 5.7.24, after I turn off the main server should I move all of the files from the Data folder to the new server and I should be fine? (overwrite the current ones that MySQL generated?)

Answer (score 0):

if you're moving a whole database schema, and you're willing to stop the first database (so it's consistent when being transfered)
Here is step

- Stop the database (or lock it)
- Go to the directory where the mysql data files are.
- Transfer over the folder (and its contents) over to the new server's mysql data directory
- Start back up the database
- On the new server, issue a 'create database' command.'
- Re-create the users & grant permissions.

But you can face issue if your my.cnf both server is different and also you have to check other configuration changes(like 8 support Roles,caching_sha2_password plugin in that,also  does not support query cache )